# Best way to see complete heists and on what difficulty

Tags: payday-2

I am currently trying to get some of the masks that you get from completing all the heists on specific difficulties and at the moment and not able to figure out which heists I have actually completed and at what difficulty I completed them on.

Is there an easy way for me to see what heists I have completed and what difficulty I completed the heists on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the contract selection screen, look in the lower left for the contract broker menu.  You can select any job (lists sorted by client) and it will show skull icons along with the number of times you've completed the job at that difficulty.

Comment: is there a way in which I can see all of the jobs? or will I just have to go through each of the jobs one at a time to see what I have completed?

Comment: @Elliott This is the only method I could find.

Comment: There is an update planned called "F.B.I. files" (http://www.overkillsoftware.com/crimefest/) and although it isn't specified what it will be, it will probably contain the stats you (and I) want.